# List of system variables not showing (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, environment-variables

When I go to "Edit the system environment variables" -> "Environment Variables" and then click on "Path" and "Edit" after, it doesn't show me the full list like in a multiline window anymore, but rather just a small window in which I can only edit the current variable. Does anyone know how to fix this?

I haven't tried anything yet, I tried searching for a solution but couldn't find one.

Comment: Not sure why there would be nothing to fix? I still get the big editor for both `Path` and `PSModulePath`, on Windows 10 22H2. I would be very surprised if they removed this great feature.

Comment: I'm with Daniel B. `Windows 10 Home 22H2 • build 19045.2486 • Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.4190.0`. Stll have `System Properties` -> `Advanced` tab -> `Environment Variables...` -> `Environment Variables` dialog -> <Select `Path` & click `Edit...`> -> 'Edit environment variable` mulitline dialog with options: `New`, `Edit`, `Browse...`, `Delete`, `Move up`, `Move Down`, `Edit text...`. `Edit` allows "in-place" editing the selected line/path; `Edit text...` displays a smaller dialog where the entrie `Path` string can be edited.

Comment: Please add a screenshot of your dialog.

Comment: The multiline window had features the current one doesn't have. The current one only shows one variable, so is there a way to bring the old window back to access those features again?

Comment: Possibly looking at this the wrong way.  How often do you really need to edit your path?  If the answer is often, then you are probably doing it wrong.  Use batch files to setup your paths for specific scenarios to launch things.  Usually people only need multiple path edits when developing with tools that mostly suck on Windows (like Python, NodeJS, Cygwin, etc) and were designed by people that don't care about this platform.  If you are developing, I suggest you use batch to setup environments and not your path.  Also make your machine faster by not querying the path every time.